# django save() doesn't effect in sqlite

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a scrapy project and want to save retrieved data in sqlite. I write scrapy spider in views file. You can see a portion of it below.

This is `views.py` file:

```
class DivarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "divar"


    def parse_first_page(self, response):
        .
        .
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='GET', callback=self.parse_each_ads)


    def parse_each_ads(self, response):
        .
        .
        .
        src = Source()
        src.name = self.name
        ctlg = Catalogue()
        ctlg.city = city
        ctlg.price = price
        ctlg.datetime = date
        ctlg.source = self.name
        ctlg.source_token = token
        src.save()
        ctlg.save()
```

This is `models.py` file:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Catalogue(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    source_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Why `src.save()` and `ctlg.save()` doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure `parse_each_ads` is even called?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, I'm sure

Comment: I'm quite sure it is not, because it should lead to some database constraint error.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm sure it is! ... because of logs in terminal

Comment: You set `ctlg.source = self.name` don't know how that will work. `ctlg.source` should be a foreign key to source. You need to save source first then `ctlg.source = src` then  save `ctlg`.

Comment: There is obviously code that is related to the problem and you did not show us.

Comment: @KlausD. I've edited the post

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same Problem, you have to reference a model, save it, and then reference another.
Your code can be better like this:

```
    src = Source.objects.create(name=self.name)
    ctlg = Catalogue(city=city, price=price, datetime=date, source=self.name, 
                     source_token=token)
```

> To create and save an object in a single step, use the `create()` method.
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

And for source attribute of Catalogue, you should pass the model reference, not model name:

```
..., source = src, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating instance and saving it, you can use the following snippet :

```
src = Source(name=self.name)
src.save()
```

And similarly with Catalogue model. For foreign key, you need to pass the instance of src in source field and that will work.  Reference [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/)

Comment: Does it show any error? Also can you try saving only Source instance to check what's the actual issue?

Comment: Yes, I tried to save only Source instance, but still doesn't work .... There is two error, but not related to this issue

Comment: Error1: ```builtins.TypeError: _findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```

Comment: Error2: ```handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
builtins.ValueError: signal only works in main thread```

Comment: Can you share where _findCaller() is defined and where it is called? Same with signal?

Comment: These are built-in ... ```File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1565, in _log
    fn, lno, func, sinfo = self.findCaller(stack_info, stacklevel)``` ... and ... ```File "/usr/lib/python3.8/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))```